# Are the cards in Zendikar vs Eldrazi standard yet, before Battle for Zendikar comes out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is the new duel deck *Zendikar vs Eldrazi* considered standard before the Battle for Zendikar comes out? I have been playing it for a few days and I don't want to waste money buy more of those cards if I cannot play them in standard.

Comment: May be better if generalised to "Are Duel Decks released during a standard rotation legal during that rotation?", that way it will be distinct from the "is a deck legal" question, and will not become outdated. Zendikar vs Eldrazi can be used as an example.

Comment: I'd like to suggest changing the question to "How do I find out whether these cards *will be* in Standard?" (future tense). That would make it not a duplicate in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

No, those cards are not all in Standard. Some already are, some aren't yet, some won't be.

- **Some already are Standard:** [Read the Bones](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Read%20the%20Bones) and others have been printed in Standard sets. You can use those.
- **The cards we know will be in Battle for Zendikar aren't standard *yet*.** They will be after that set actually comes out and enters Standard rotation. *Dominator Drone* and others aren't available in Standard yet.
- **Some are old cards that might not become Standard at all.** Like other duel decks, *Zendikar vs Eldrazi* contains many cards from *past* sets no longer in Standard. [Butcher of Malakir](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Butcher%20of%20Malakir) and [Corpsehatch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Corpsehatch) have not been seen in Standard since the original Zendikar block several years ago. There's no guarantee these cards will become Standard at all.

If you're expecting to buy exclusively cards usable in Standard, Duel Decks are not the product for you. Buy those to actually duel with, or if you play a more open format like Modern or Commander.

Comment: Cards to note in particular are the dual lands in the decks, like Akoum Refuge, which is not in Standard and *definitely* won't be reprinted in BFZ.

Comment: What makes you say that Akoum Refuge definitely won't be reprinted in BFZ, at least more-so than any standard card?

Comment: @GendoIkari it already has several full dual land cycles and there are loads still in standard

Comment: @Gendolkari Fair question though, I've removed the speculation.

Comment: @GendoIkari We already know what the dual land cycle in BFZ is, and it isn't that. But I'll admit that it's possible that they'll print more than one of those. A better example would probably be Rocky Tar Pit, because Mark Rosewater explicitly said that they would not print fetchlands in this block.

Comment: @doppelgreener We have one full dual land cycle for BFZ.